# .htaccess Rewriting parameter to path

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite parameters to a path with htaccess.

Example:
https://test.link?test123 -> https://test.link/test123

The website is running with PHP 8.0.

I have following code in my .htaccess that works on localhost:

```
RewriteEngine on 

[...]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But as i'm hosting on Hostinger this does not work.
So my question is do I need to enable/disable some plugins or something OR is it just blocked by Hostinger somehow?

If it helps anyone, here is my index.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'ga_linked_database.php'; #just connecting to the DB, works fine
    $new_uri = "";
    if(!empty($_GET)){
        foreach($_GET as $key => $val){
            $u = $key;
            $new_uri = str_replace('/', '', $u);
            $sql = "[...]";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
            if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $new_uri);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                $resultnum = mysqli_num_rows($resultData);
                if($resultnum > 0){
                    $c_query = "[...]";
                    $stmts = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmts, $c_query)){
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmts, "s", $new_uri);
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmts);
                        mysqli_stmt_close($stmts);
                    }else{
                        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
                        http_response_code(500);
                        exit();
                    }
                    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)){
                        $long_url = $row["long_url"];
                        header("Location: " . $long_url);
                    }else{
                        echo "<h1>Error - unknown error</h1>";
                        exit();
                    }
                }else{
                            echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
                            exit;
                }
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }else{
                http_response_code(500);
                echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
                exit();
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "<h1>File / not found</h1>"
        exit;
    }
?>
```

(Don't judge my PHP code, it's just a project for myself)

Comment: Just to be clear, and I apologize if this comes off wrong, but you know this is a two-step process, right? You update htaccess custom links, and then you change your entire application to use those links instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware. If I get for example "youtube" from the database I want to be able to access https://youtube.com with https://test.link/youtube. The application works just fine on localhost. Hope you know what I mean.

Comment: You might be better served by Apache's `FallbackResource` directive, along with the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP. This avoids messing with the query string and regex, and personally I find it easier to troubleshoot. It can replace all of the posted htaccess lines, for instance.

Comment: I'd try putting something completely wrong into htaccess, and see if your host complains, just to make sure it is even reading it in the first place

Comment: The rest of the htaccess works fine it's just this part that doesn't work. I'll give FallbackResource a try. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I think Hostinger uses Litespeed server and i guess FallbackResource is unsupported (https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/forum/threads/request-list-of-un-supported-apache-directives.8824/)

Comment: example is invalid, the slash after domain is required. on the other hand the rewrite rule have slash in query which is reserved character so its invalid too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make adjustments to my PHP code and `.htaccess` file because I had previously done something similar and had a slightly similar issue due to `.htaccess` behavior varying with server settings (in my instance). Just to give you a heads up, even though you said, "do not judge my code," the truth is that this is a bad way to get the results you're after. I'm sure there are many more elegant ways to accomplish whatever it is you're aiming for. After X amount of time passed and I gained some experience, I had to "update" this project of mine, and even though I left a lot of comments and explanations of what I did where, I hit myself in the head because I barely understood anything.

Anyways, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

This rule works like this:

The `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$` line determines whether or not there is a non-empty query string.
The `RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1? [R=301,L]` line rewrites the root URL (`/`) as a path containing the query string (caught by `%1`). The `?` at the end removes the original query string from the rewritten URL, `R=301` indicates a permanent redirect, and `L` indicates that this is the final rule that will be executed if the condition is met.

Once you've set up this `.htaccess file`, your PHP script will get requests in the path format. A request to https://test.link?test123, for example, will be rebuilt as https://test.link/test123.

Then, rather than parsing the query string, your PHP script must parse the URL path.

```
require_once 'ga_linked_database.php'; 

    $path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $pathComponents = explode('/', trim($path, '/'));
    $new_uri = $pathComponents[0]; // With asumption that first component is what you need... after this goes rest of your code
```

--The path portion of the URL is extracted using `parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH).`
--The path is divided into its component parts using `explode('/',trim($path,'/')).`
--`$pathComponents[0]` obtains the path's initial component, which is test123 in the case of the original query argument.